# I need to send a POST request to an api using an XML request structure in java

Tags: java, xml, curl

```
String urly = "myurl";
URL url = new URL(myurl);
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
con.setRequestMethod("POST");
con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/xml");
con.setDoOutput(true);
DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
wr.writeBytes(xml);
wr.flush();
```

i am not sure whether this sends the request using xml request structure which is stored in String "xml". I dont know any other way to send request using XML.

```
int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);
BufferedReader iny = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
          String output;
          StringBuffer res = new StringBuffer();

          while ((output = iny.readLine()) != null) {
           res.append(output);
          }
          iny.close();
           wr.close(); 
          //printing result from response
          System.out.println(res.toString());
```

The response i am getting shows Invalid Request.

Comment: Are you getting any error? Are you referring to servlet as api ?

Comment: No i am not getting any error, just i am not getting the desired response. I am referring to URL as api.

Comment: here you send whatever is in the `xml` variable. if the xml variable contains an actual XML file, you should be good to go. how do you generate the xml variable?

Comment: XML variable contains XML string and it is mostly hardcoded except some fields which need to be filled dynamically. What i think is that maybe the XML is being written in bytes through writeBytes() method on the server and i need to send request in XML format not bytes, any idea how to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

The generated XML was wrong, it needed to be checked.